Distributing candies problem: Seeking verification of my solution

There are 20 identical candies. How many ways to divide the candies among 3 children so that:

Every child has at least one candy
Every child has at least 2 candies
The first child has at least 1 candy, the second child has at least 2 candies, and the third child has at most 3 candies.


I found this problem online but it doesn't come with a key so I'm not sure if my solution is correct and optimal. I hope to receive some advice. Thank you!


Using the stars-and-bars method, I get $\dbinom{19}{2}.$
Substract the cases where only either one of the children has $1$ candy and either any two of the children have $1$ candy each from the above result: $\dbinom{19}{2} - 3\dbinom{16}{1} - 3$
Since the third child has at most $3$ candies, there are only $3$ valid choices for the second bar. Fix the second bar for each case, leaving us $17$, $16$, and $15$ possible places for the first bar, so there are $48$ cases.


Looks good. You can use the stars and bars for the second part also

@stochs Hi, thank you! I actually used stars and bars to calculate the exception cases, but I suspect there is a way to calculate the favorable outcomes directly, which you seem to be referring to?

Yes, you have to place two bars in 20-(3*2)=14 stars. So you get $16 \choose 2$

As @Robert Shore pointed out you missed a case in the third part. Sorry for the confusion

@stochs That's very clever. Thank you!

Your first answer is correct.
The easiest way to verify the second answer is to use stars and bars to determine the number of solutions to $y_1+y_2+y_3=14$, where $y_i$ is the number of candies in excess of $2$ received by child $i$.  Stars and bars tells you this answer is $\displaystyle \binom{16}{2}=120$.  Thus, your answer is correct.
For the third answer, first calculate the number of solutions to $y_1+y_2+x_3=17$, where there is no constraint on $x_3$.  Again, stars and bars tells you there are $\displaystyle \binom{19}{2}=171$ unconstrained solutions.  Now calculate the number of "forbidden" solutions to the first equation; i.e., those where $x_3 \geq 4$.  That is the number of solutions to $y_1+y_2+y_3=13$.  There are $\displaystyle \binom{15}{2}=105$ such "forbidden" solutions.  Thus, the answer to part $3$ is $171-105=66$.  Your solution is wrong because you have overlooked the possibility that the third child gets no candies, which happens in $18$ permissible combinations.

Hi, thank you very much! I found the interpretation of "at least" and "at most" in your solution super clever! It brings the problem to a standard version which makes calculation so much faster. Thank you very much again!
